# RoR passing hash to object initialize causes "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

While I understand what this error means, I don't seem to do anything wrong that can cause it. Let's assume I have 2 files:

auths_controller.rb:

```
def index
    config = GmailOauth::Application.credentials.google[:web].stringify_keys!
    gmail_client = Gmail::GmailClient.new(config)
end
```

config is just a hash class with symbols, in this example I even stringify the keys so I can access them like: config["client_id"]

Here's the output of "puts config" in this file:

> {"client_id"=>"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", "project_id"=>"xxx", "auth_uri"=>"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "token_uri"=>"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", "client_secret"=>"xxx"}

All good, right? Here's the GmailClient file:

```
module Gmail
    class GmailClient
        def initialize(config)
          puts config # this already throws the error!
          exit
```

I don't understand why just pass the method call I get the error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: so, the error is surely caused by that `puts config` line?

Comment: Why do you use `stringify_keys!`? Maybe the root of the problem is that it modifies original object? Try to use `stringify_keys` instead.

Comment: Have you tried passing `config` as it is and doing `stringify` in the `GmailClient` class? If that throws the error, then try hardcoding the `config` in controller, with only a dummy key-value pair to see if that works.

Comment: @andHapp and actually hardcoding it throws the same error... I'm puzzled now even more. `def initialize()` `cf = {"test" => "hello"}` in this sequence of lines it throws error on the latter... :|

Comment: What a revelation for it was that rails doesn't reload files that were changed, so this whole error was an old error it remembered on that line and all I had to do is restart manually rails server. Bummer. How do I automate it? It doesn't seem practical to do it that way. No hot reload in Ruby world?